# How to disable text input to EditText from barcode bluetooth reader?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I work with Bluetooth barcode reader. It works like a physical keyboard, when EditText focused, it inserts characters. When EditText not focused I process events from reader in dispatchKeyEvent(). I need to disable barcode input when EditText is focused and soft keyboard input must be accesible.

Comment: You actually can't. You should add en TextHandler on your EditText and check the length of your String to know when to process your search.

Comment: But I don't know length of barcodes, maybe it will be different.

Comment: You can try to add a barcode validator to check if the current String can be a barcode or not.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextView instead. Or add the tag :

> android:editable="false"

Comment: I have tried it, but soft keyboard input must be accessible.